# Calling a function on a HTML check box change without submission using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create a ASP.NET web site. I have a DIV that is hidden by default and I am trying to display it if the user checks a check box. I am wondering if there is a way using C# to immediately display the DIV as soon as the user checks the box. I can't seem to find a way to recognize the change in state without the form being first submitted. I can easily achieve this using JavaScript however this is for a uni assignment and requires functionality to be implemented in C#.
This is the HTML for the checkBox:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Limit Stations To My Location<asp:CheckBox ID="limitOptions" runat="server" onClick="toggleOptions()" /> 
    <br /><br />
    <div id="locationOptions" runat="server" hidden="hidden">
        Radius (KM)<asp:TextBox ID="radius" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="updateList" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="updateList_Click"/>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with C# in code behind. Add a `OnCheckedChanged` event to the CheckBox and set the `AutoPostBack` to true and handle the change. Note that a `Panel` becomes a `div` in HTML.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="limitOptions" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="limitOptions_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:Panel ID="locationOptions" runat="server" Visible="false">
    Radius (KM) <asp:TextBox ID="radius" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

However this causes a PostBack, so just using JavaScript could be a better option.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="limitOptions" runat="server" onclick="toggleOptions()" />

<div id="locationOptions" runat="server" style="display: none">
    Radius (KM)<asp:TextBox ID="radius" runat="server" Text="100"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleOptions() {
        var id = '#<% =locationOptions.ClientID %>';
        if ($(id).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(id).slideDown('fast', function () { });
        } else {
            $(id).slideUp('fast', function () { });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD. That did exactly what I was looking for however after reading up on PostBack I think you are right and I will just go with JavaScript anyway. Thanks for your prompt reply.